# Can not copy files properly to docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Hello i am trying to recreate inside a docker `image` my host folder that contains:

- **Publish** (folder containing a `.NET app` )
- dockerfile
- conf.json

**dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore 
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/publish/Bench.dll"]
EXPOSE 8300
```

When i am trying to see what it created using `docker exec -it <id> bash` it just takes all the content of `publish` and throws it inside `app` without copying `conf.json`.

I have also tried with 
`COPY . /app`,

`COPY /publish /app`+`COPY conf.json /app` to no avail.
Whatever i am trying it won't copy the folder `as-is` and it wont put the `json` file beside it.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is all of your files in /app of your host ?

Comment: The folder in the host looks like the one  i posted.It has the `publish` directory, the `dockerfile` and the `json` file i want to copy.

Comment: What is the absolute path of the folder on the host ?

Comment: This is the absolute path :`C:\Project\builds\bench\backend\publish`.It does copy the `publish` folder and the `dockerfile` but not the `json`.

Answer (score 0):

So I tested this out. I had the publish folder dockerfile and conf.json in the same directory where I build the image from. That is the key. Here I am using nginx as my base image. The following is the command I used to build the nginx image

```
docker build -t test/nginx .
```

and the dockerfile is as below. So I create the app directory by using the RUN command. You will have to use the similar command in .net to create that directory if it doesn't exist. Also pay attention to the docker build logs. It will tell you things that are important. Also you could add an ls command in the dockerfile to list the files in the folder `/app` if you want to.

```
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
```

After I create a container from the image I built, i can navigate to /app folder and view my 
Dockerfile, config.json and publish folder in there. Hope this helps
Let me know if you have any questions